# Img not loading on Django Bootstrap Carousel

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap

Hi carousel is showing on page but not loading images.
Static files collected and this is my code:

```
<div class="item active">
        <img src="{% static 'img/image.png' %}" alt="First slide">
```

Where am I wrong? thanks

Comment: These lines of code are fine. Problem is elsewhere. Check image location by trying to open image directly in browser.

Comment: Your static files such as `.js`, `.css` files are loading?